# Recurring and non-recurring items in single PayPal checkout flow

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, shopware

I'm currently migrating a website from WooCommerce to Shopware 6, which needs to support recurring payments for a membership subscription.

WooCommerce is still using PayPal Standard, which allows you to mix non-recurring line items with a recurring subscription, in a single checkout flow.

Shopware 6 uses the REST API, which doesn't appear to support this ability and the only solution appears to be using the Javascript SDK:

- User clicks Pay with PayPal.
- Subscription is created via `actions.subscription.create`
- Dialog is displayed requesting approval.
- Customer approves.
- Submit original checkout.
- Redirect to PayPal.
- Complete payment.
- Redirect back to website with confirmation.

A potential solution I'm looking into now is changing the return URL of the initial order creation to redirect to a billing agreement approval URL and have the return URL's of that redirect back to the original return url.

Overly complicated and the worse UX I've ever seen.

Before I tear what's left of my hair out, does anyone have any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

Although it isn't the solution I was hoping for, I ended up removing the Shopware 6 PayPal plugin and implementing my own payment method using the NVP API.

From the user perspective, there is only one approval process. In the backend, once the user has approved the transaction (that has been marked as needing a billing agreement) the transaction is verified and then a recurring profile is created.

Comment: Theoretically shopware already supports multiple transactions for a single order. So the database structure should be prepared for these scenarios.

Comment: @Rotfuchs Shopware it self isn't the issue - it's PayPal. Shopware 6's PayPal payment handler only uses the REST API. If you are just purchasing normal products it's perfect, but if you want to combine both recurring and non-recurring items, your only option at the moment is to uninstall it and implement your own solution (which I ended up doing.) Sad times.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to combine Subscriptions and one-time payments in a single checkout. Such items even require different parameters on the PayPal SDK line, if using the PayPal buttons to show an in-context experience.

The in-context experience is best, since it involves no redirects away from your site to PayPal and back. Here is the flow for one-time payments:

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

A similar (separate) flow can be used for [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/). Only one subscription can be approved at a time.

Comment: This was my concern. I love how PayPal is going down the same route as Stripe Elements and making everything more UX/Front End friendly, but a very common use case has been ignored when allowing vendors to sell both recurring and non-recurring items. 

We also use Stripe, which I am able to modify the payment intent to include a payment plan before it's sent to Stripe for authorisation. I was hoping I could do the same with PayPal but it looks like i'll have to implement my own payment method for Shopware that uses PayPal Standard :( 

Thanks for the input though!